# Which event fires when selecting an Item in ASP.NET DetailView?

Tags: .net, asp.net, events, detailsview

I have put a select button in my DetailView and I want to catch its event, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Are you unable to catch the event from the button itself?

Comment: it's not exactly a button, I just added a select command field which is actualy a link, which is part of the DetailView itself, so I don't know how to catch that.

Comment: Here's a link to the DetailsView Events doc, but there appear to only be events for Insert, Update, and Delete buttons. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview_events.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemCommand` will be fired

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Is it only fired for selecting? If so, why does it have such irrelative naming?

Comment: no its fired for other event as well, like Inserting and updating. But for selection, you could add logic in this event.

Comment: Thanks, but I have another problem now, how do I get field values? It doesnt have SelectedIndex like GridView

Comment: Seems like you answered while I was editing, can you help with field values too?

Comment: When I select something in DetailView, How do I know it's content? SelectedValue only returns the key, not every column's value.

Comment: @MuhammadAkhtar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2631/discussion-between-atomerz-and-muhammad-akhtar)